# Was bedeutet "wohl"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Ich würde gerne die Bedeutung verstehen:

> Dann hast du **wohl** keine Zeit.

Was bedeutet hier *wohl*?

Comment: Please clarify in english.

Comment: *"Dann hast du keine Zeit"* simply translates to *"Then, you don't have time"*, or *"So you don't have time"*, depending on context. I don't understand what you're asking about in the second sentence. *"Wohl"* has quite a number of different meanings, depending on context. In any event please clarify your question.

Comment: I think we should refrain from guessing the intended question and modifying the post.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: in case you disagreed with editing obvious errors you should start a [Meta] discussion asking to clarify our policy on that.

Comment: @Takkat, if the error would have been obvious, others would not have asked for clarification. I guessed the same as you, but I would not have felt comfortable to edit it.

Comment: If the asker is not able to correctly write the German sentence that they want translated ... If the asker cannot even take the care to post the wording of the question correctly, well then, how do they expect an answer? If it takes edits from the community to even phrase the question correctly, wouldn't it be better to just delete the question? If the asker cannot be bothered to employ even the most simple means of quality control before posting, how can they expect that people bother to find a solution to an ill-asked question that requires community edits to be legible?

Answer (score 8):

The number one function of "wohl" is to express an assumption.

> Dann hast du wohl keine Zeit.

This means something like..

> Well, then you don't have time I suppose/guess.

Just like "to guess" and "to suppose" the person who is saying that can very well be very sure about the other person's not having time, so the assumption is just used to distinguish it from a statement.

> Dann hast du keine Zeit.

That sounds as if I am telling that to the other person... like...

> Think boy! If you need to do this and this and this, then you won't have time.

"wohl" has some other meanings too and emphasis actually plays a big role but more on that as well as more examples can be found in [this article](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/meaning-wohl/) on my blog.

Answer (score 3):

In addition

it can be used always to make something sound less resolute, e. g. to be more polite or if something is not certain, assumptions, etc

> Hätten Sie wohl einen Moment Zeit?
>   Der Zug wird wohl[/vermutlich] schon weg sein.

Also it is used for pointing out something that turned out to be false, like a false assumption. Its not a provoking statement, but its not neutral though.

> Du hattest wohl[/wahrscheinlich] gedacht damit sei die Sache erledigt.

---

More rarely `wohl` is also used as emphatic confirmation or when objecting

> Ich hab' das wohl verstanden.
>   Ich hab' das wohl verstanden, jedoch will mir nicht einleuchten, dass...

Comment: About the "Du hattest wohl gedacht..." part... I don't think that wohl does the implications here. The phrasing as an indirect question in combination with tone does. The reason I say that is because you can put in for example "wirklich" instead of "wohl". All the implications are still the same, only that you're not assuming, you're knowing.

Comment: @emanuel It's indeed the tone that matters. Was looking for niche usage of the word..

Answer (score 1):

http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wohl

Bedeutungen:
**[1] wahrscheinlich, vermutlich**
[2] veraltend: gut

The bold one is the one applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

You can say "Dann hast Du *wohl* keine Zeit". This would typically be used in the sense of `probably`, inferring disappointment. For example:

A: Gehst Du heute Abend mit mir ins Kino?

B: Nun, ich muss meine Mutter anrufen, meine Steuererklärung machen, und meine Wohnung putzen.

A: Dann hast Du wohl keine Zeit.

I deliberately chose excuses that one wouldn't prefer to going to the cinema, normally. When Speaker A says "Du hast wohl keine Zeit", he expresses disappointment, and a certain disbelief in Speaker B's excuses. I don't know what the origin of "wohl" is, in this case, it's just how i would use the word.

Comment: Disappointment - yes, disbelief - IMO no